# Find the roots of the polynomial in $Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

The polynomial is: $2x^{219} + 3x^{74} + 2x^{57} + 3x^{44}$. Find the zeros.

Now my first step, which I believe shall be correct is to reduce the exponents of the polynomial in mod 5.

Thus: 219 becomes 4, 74 becomes 4, 57 becomes 3, and 44 becomes 4.

And our new polynomial ends up simplyfying to $8x^{4} + 2x^{2}$.

Is this getting me on the right track, because doing these calculations in modulus is pretty tricky.

Is there a more simple theorem that I can use to figure this out easier?

Edit: My attempt

I'm assuming i'm on the right track. So I simplify the whole thing down to $2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 3 = 0$

I factor that into $(x^2 + 1)(2x + 1) = 0$

And get roots $i, -i, and -1/2$. Is my logic correct?

Comment: Ahh man. Why not? It was allowed when I computed a polynomial. Why cant I simplify it like that to find zeros? What stuff is allowed? There must be something I can do to bring those powers down, right?

Comment: Hint: try a few easy values of $x$, for a start.

Comment: This is $\mathbb Z_5$, remember.  The possible values are $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not correct.  $x^5 = x$ in $\mathbb Z_5$, so  $x^j = x^k$ if $j \equiv k \mod 4$ (not mod $5$) and $j,k > 0$.

Comment: Oh crap. Yes you are correct. So would simplyfying it to $2x^3 + 3x^{2} + 2x + 3$ be a correct move?

Comment: Almost.   $x^{44}$ is not $1$ though, in the case $x=0$.